# AWS amplify build status after build complete

Tags: shell, deployment, build, hosting, aws-amplify

I am working on Amplify Build settings, I want to trigger an email with updated Build status.
Also wrote a AWS command in amplify build settings (postDeploy), but that returns the "RUNNING" build status, as the command is also a part of build phase.

I'm looking for a solution to achieve latest build status and that's only possible once build is completed and the script executes.

And AWS amplify does not provide Deploy/postDeploy Phase in the build settings.

Have tried `node-cron`, but its still working same as previous and blocking the shell untill cron is triggered. Also tried a few custom bash scripts with sleep (secs), it also blocks the terminal and the returned build status is still same as its executing in between the build phase.

** I could use SNS, but looking for some custom build message with attachments.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Amplify provides several ways to get updates on your build, allowing you to track the progress and status of your application.

1. **Amplify Console:** The AWS Amplify Console provides a comprehensive view of all your Amplify applications. For each app, you can view the frontend environments and backend environments. You can click on each build to get a detailed view of the build, deploy, and verify stages.
2. **Notifications:** AWS Amplify integrates with AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS). You can set up notifications for specific events like build start, build success, and build failure. You will receive these notifications as configured, via methods like email, SMS, or AWS Lambda functions.
   [image: notifications for AWS Amplify]

3. **AWS CloudWatch:** AWS Amplify also integrates with AWS CloudWatch. CloudWatch collects monitoring and operational data in the form of logs, metrics, and events, providing you with a unified view of AWS resources, applications, and services that run on AWS. You can use CloudWatch to detect anomalous behavior in your environments, set alarms, visualize logs and metrics side by side, take automated actions, troubleshoot issues, and discover insights to keep your applications running smoothly.
   [image: monitoring app]